# Searching a string that contains space or a full stop (eg "txt 1" or "txt.1"), using PHP, returns no records

Tags: php, mysql, space

I am facing the following problem.
I have a table with a column (CHAR 10) that contains keywords that some of them have a space or a full stop in them.
eg:

```
sessionid
SES1
SES2
SES2 1 <--
SES2 1 <--
SES2 1 <--
SES2.1 <--
SES2.2 <--
SES3_1
SES3_1
SES4
```

The following code in the PHP program returns no records !

```
Select * from TABLE where sessionid="SES2 1";
```

or

```
Select * from TABLE where sessionid="SES2.1";
```

var dumping to check the SQL string and copying & pasting it into "MySQL connector" the SQL command works fine! Returns the expected records.
What am i doing wrong in PHP?

PHP code in utf8.

Database and table encoding utf8

The following SQL command though in PHP works fine:

```
Select * from TABLE where sessionid="SES3_1";
```

...Here is the code

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, DB_NAME);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
...
...
# $stru_s_row['SessionID'] comes from another query
# every other session search works fine
$sql="SELECT * FROM `table` where `SessionID`= '".$stru_s_row['SessionID']."'";
# checking the SQL command 
var_dump($sql);
$rows = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$nRows = mysqli_num_rows($rows);
...
```

Comment: Show your PHP code!

Comment: I see no problem in the SQL, the problem lays inside PHP

Comment: mysqli_select_db($conn, DB_NAME);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

...
...

# $stru_s_row['SessionID'] comes from another query
# every other session search works fine

$sql="SELECT * FROM `table` where `SessionID`= '".$stru_s_row['SessionID']."'";

# checking the SQL command 
var_dump($sql);

$rows = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$nRows = mysqli_num_rows($rows);
...

Comment: The code works fine with any other piece of string (not having space or .)

Comment: Please add the code to the question and not as a comment.